# Can't get Server time asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I am trying to get the server time instead of the client side date and time. When I use this code it gives me the time on my computer when I change the time. I would like to have it just keep the server time.

```
<script runat="server">

    Protected serverTime As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now()

</script>
```

I output in my asp form here

```
<%= serverTime.ToString()%>
```

Comment: Did you actually deploy this code to a server or are you running this on your dev machine?

Comment: That's it, thank you wasn't even thinking about being on my dev.

Comment: Although you should run your server on UTC time, it is safer to use `DateTime.UtcNow()` so that it stays consistent. Then convert it to local time for the client as needed.

Comment: Thank you I will use that in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Any of below will work:

```
Protected serverTime As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
Protected serverTime As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
Protected serverTime As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
Protected serverTime As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
Protected serverTime As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: True, made mistake here.Thanks!